# How do you install Single Player Commands on Minecraft for Ubuntu? I need Step-by-Step instructions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to download this Mod for Minecraft from this link http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-125-single-player-commands-v322-official-download/

I have no idea how to install the mod. I've seen videos on Youtube but most of their comments state that there wrong. I have Ubuntu.

Comment: What part of the install are you having difficulty with? The install instructions seem pretty clear and OS independent.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Risugami's Mac OS X scripts for applying modifications, I have made these two scripts that will 1) open the minecraft.jar, which allows you to drag and drop the *.class files into the mctmp folder. And 2) close and apply whatever changes were made to the mctmp folder, to the minecraft.jar

Here:
openjar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
mkdir mctmp
cd mctmp
jar -xf ~/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar
```

closejar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd mctmp
rm META-INF/MOJANG_C.*
jar -uf ~/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar ./
cd ..
rm -rf mctmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise installing it the traditional way (in the jar) instead of the automated installer. You can use this method for any mod that needs to be installed inside the jar.

1. Download the manual installation version from the forum post.
2. Find your minecraft.jar. This isn't the one you use to launch the game, it's the one in your .minecraft/bin directory. Which should be in /home/username/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar.
3. Extract all the class files from the zip to a temporary folder.
4. Open up your minecraft.jar using Archive Manager or Ark or whatever you use.
5. Drag all the class files from the temporary folder into Archive Manager or Ark or whatever archiving tool you use.
6. Delete the META-INF folder.
7. There was a WorldEdit.jar in the zip too, so take that and copy that into .minecraft/bin.

EDIT: Don't forget to backup your minecraft.jar in case something goes awry.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download the **.ZIP** file
2. Extract it to some directory.
3. Go to the directory you just created.
4. In a new window, go to your *home* directory (also known as *~*)
5. Look for `.minecraft/`. By default you will not see this so press <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> to see them
6. Look for a file called `minecraft.jar` inside the `bin/` directory
7. Rename that file to `minecraft.jar.zip`
8. Unzip it
9. Drag all files ending with `.CLASS` into the `minecraft.jar` FOLDER
   (all the files except `WorldEdit.jar`)
10. Go back to the folder that has the `minecraft.jar` in it
11. Drag the `WorldEdit.jar` file into this directory.
12. Go back into the `minecraft.jar` *folder*, not the `.jar` file
13. Delete the `META-INF` folder.
14. You're done! However, Minecraft may not launch from your web browser. If this happens, launch Minecraft  from Terminal or the <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> dialog  like this:

    ```
    java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
    ```

Comment: You don't need to rename a .jar file to .zip. This isn't Windows, it's Ubuntu, and you can extract an archive in GNOME2 or Unity simply by right-clicking on it.

Comment: Still is that incorrect? Does that call for a downvote? Let's look at what the downvote button says: `This answer is not useful.` Does the extra step of renaming it make it not useful?